# Wide char to multibyte issue

Tags: c++, windows, utf-8

In one of my project I need to support UTF-8 in Windows C++.

Current code is using `wcstombs` where Chinese language is not getting converted properly. I replaced the `wcstombs` with `WideCharToMultiByte`. After testing this works fine in Windows 7 and Windows XP SP3 I have.

But in one of the old machine Windows XP SP3 with say Chinese or CZech language pack is installed. I understand this would impact registry as well. There the application is behaving differently.

When I use `wcstombs` while doing opertator overloading of `<<` its working fine. When I use `WideCharToMultiByte` in the same its not working as expected.

Without the change in registry setting (installing language pack), `WideCharToMultiByte` is working fine.

Am I correct in thinking that the language pack installation can impact registry changes which affect this behavior? Please help me in understanding if there could be anything else also which may affect the behavior.

Comment: Are you sure that WideCharToMultiByte isn't returning a byte array?  If that's the case then maybe somehow it is getting mixed up with the binary shift operator (which is also '<<')

Answer (score 0):

By default, WideCharToMultiByte will accept a char pointer and return convered multibyte array.

Also he mentioned as working on all OS other than XP where language registry is changed. So I dont think the issue is becaose of binary shif operator.